# Cannot get Signal R working due to cors issue - blocked by cors policy

Tags: reactjs, cors, signalr, cors-anywhere

I am using React with Signal R

I have a standard web application that hosts my hub.

When I send messages all works perfectly in the web page for the web application

I also have a react application that is hosted on port 3000

I changed IIS Express settings as per below

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
      <redirectHeaders>
        <clear />
      </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

and my server side Startup for cors etc is below

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("cors",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
        });

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("cors");
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

On the React side I have implemented as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      nick: '',
      message: '',
      messages: [],
      hubConnection: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const protocol = new signalR.JsonHubProtocol();
    const transport = signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: signalR.LogLevel.Trace,
    };

    // create the connection instance
    var hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:44360/chatHub", options)
      .withHubProtocol(protocol)
      .build();

    this.setState({ hubConnection }, () => {
      this.state.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

      this.state.hubConnection.on('SendMessage', (user, message) => {
        const text = `${user}: ${message}`;
        const messages = this.state.messages.concat([text]);

        console.log('ssss');

        this.setState({ messages });
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />

        <div>
          {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => (
            <span style={{display: 'block'}} key={index}> {message} </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chat;
```

As you can see I have connected to the exact port where my server application is

I get an entry in the log to say I am connected

However, I never actually get any messages?

My hub in the web application is shown below

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I thought I had resolved the Cors issues but when I left the web page open for a while I got the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:44360/chatHub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried proxying your Requests? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: No never heard of that will take a look later but initial glance seems complicated!

Comment: Basically adding `'proxy': 'http://localhost:44360'` in package.json and you'd then invoke your request without the baseUrl(http://localhost:44360)

Comment: I added that to the package.json in the root.  But it does not work because it just goes to local host : 3000 / chathub (without spaces obviously)

Comment: Is this def compatible with SignalR seems strange that its being ignored totally.  I used the setupProxy.js approach in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined origins both in IIS config and in code.  You should only specify origins in IIS config if (1) you only trust a single origin for all applications on the server, or (2) you trust all origins for all applications on the server.

When specified in the config at server level, every http context in the pipeline has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header added.  Then, the `WithOrigins(<origin>)` method appends another value to it.

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

> 6.4 Implementation Considerations This section is non-normative.
>
> Resources that wish to enable themselves to be shared with multiple
>   Origins but do not respond uniformly with "*" must in practice
>   generate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header dynamically in
>   response to every request they wish to allow. As a consequence,
>   authors of such resources should send a Vary: Origin HTTP header or
>   provide other appropriate control directives to prevent caching of
>   such responses, which may be inaccurate if re-used across-origins.

Answer (score 8):

After hours of trying I finally got this to work

I am going to keep this question here along with my solution to help others

First - In ConfigureServices:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddSignalR();
  }
```

Ensuring Cors is before Signal R

Then in Configure

```
        // Make sure the CORS middleware is ahead of SignalR.
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000") //Source
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                .AllowCredentials();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<MYHubClass>("/myHub");
        });
```

Ensuring that UseCors is before UseEndpoints

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Cors like this:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});
```

Comment: That doesnt work - I get the error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: Any other ideas?  I cant get anything to work at all!  Even putting the server into Azure and having the react on local machine doesnt work.  Really really frustrating!

Comment: @Paul today happened to me the same. After some ours of troubleshooting I just deleted the service from Azure and created again and the CORS problem was gone. Don't know how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** in CORS setting in your Azure Web app.
[I included a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLfa9.png)